# Trying to get property of non-object cms transfer

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem: I deleted one of the categories in CMS. After that I restored it, but after recovery, the site with the English localization stopped starting although the second type of localization works. Error:

> Trying to get property of non-object
>   (`public_html/resources/theme/menu/default.blade.php`)

`Default.blade.php`  code:

```
@foreach($items as $item)
    <li>
        <a href="{{CMS::getPermalink($item['page_id'],$item['url'])}}">{{$item['node_text']}}</a>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

`CmsService.php` (`getPermalink`):

```
public static function getPermalink($page_id, $fallback_url = '#')
    {
        $res = $fallback_url;
        if ($page_id) {
            $locale = LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocale();
            $settingsRepo = app('SiteSettings');
            if ($settingsRepo->getSetting('home_page_id', $locale) == $page_id) {
                return LaravelLocalization::getLocalizedURL(null, '/');
            }
            $repo = app('PageRepositoryService');
            $page = $repo->find($page_id);
            if (isset($page)) {

                if ($page->pageType->has_archive) {
                    return self::getArchiveLink($page->pageType->key) . $page->path;
                } else {
                    $res = $page->path;
                }

            } else {
                $res = $fallback_url;
            }
        }
        $url = LaravelLocalization::getLocalizedURL(null, $res);
        return ($page_id == null and ($fallback_url == null or $fallback_url == "#")) ? '#' : $url;
    }
```

Yep for sure there's all message from error

> (6/6) ErrorException Trying to get property of non-object (View:
>   /`public_html/resources/theme/menu/default.blade.php`) (View:
>   /`public_html/resources/theme/menu/default.blade.php`) (View:
>   /`public_html/resources/theme/menu/default.blade.php`) (View:
>   /`public_html/resources/theme/menu/default.blade.php`) (View:
>   /`public_html/resources/theme/menu/default.blade.php`)
>
> in CmsService.php (line 196)

169 line in `CmsService.php` is

```
if ($page->pageType->has_archive) {
```

Comment: Could you add the rest of the error message please?

Comment: looks like '$page' is not what you expect. make a var_dump and check if '$page' contains the information you need. 'isset()' does not mean that the information you are looking for is returned.Normaly i use 'if($page->count() !== 0)' to check if I get one or more results.